# Loading paragraph data into Teradata

Tags: csv, teradata, informatica, linefeed

I am loading CSV file data into Teradata table, I have a record as below,

```
Hardware support - EMC,"Geneva, Switzerland",,Hardware support.,Hardware support.,0,Other (describe),"All of the following:

Electronic
Fax machine
Hard Copy
In Person
Mail Delivery
Telephone",No,Immediate,,10235,82,18364,3/23/2018 14:04,3/23/2018 14:06,pfriel,pfriel,,,,
```

when i load below field data into Teradata column, The first line (All of the following:) is getting populated, and the remaining part is not loading. The remaining fields are populating as '?', When i check the record in Notepad++, a LineFeed(LF) is attached to each line in below field. I have to remove that LineFeed character, so that entire field can be moved to teradata column.

```
"All of the following:

Electronic
Fax machine
Hard Copy
In Person
Mail Delivery
Telephone"
```

Comment: You need to give us a lot more information. How are you trying to load the file into your table?  How are you defining your row and field delimiters? Do you only have LFs in your file, or CR/LF for the actual record breaks?

Comment: I am loading CSV file thru informatica into Teradata, each record has CRLF at the end. But the given field data spread across multiple lines, each line ending with LF.

Comment: I'm adding the `informatica` tag in hopes of finding some experts there as this is an informatica issue, not a Teradata issue. If this question were centered around how to consume this quote encapsulated data through TPT then it would be another story.

Comment: If you can't handle it in Informatica, you can use sed or awk (assuming you're on *nix) to replace the line feeds, but I'm not sure what you'd replace them with.  I wouldn't consider trying to store formatted data in a database a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to specify a different line delimiter in your Source Qualifier or replace the LF for this column before loading the CSV. In order to achieve that you may either run a command task that will do the replace, or specify the `Command` as the Source Qualifier input and put the command there to read directly. In both cases a `sed` or `awk` should be used, as mentioned by @Andrew in the comments.